# Amazon S3 video doesn't work in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, video, amazon-s3

I have a problem accessing videos on AmazonS3.

I get links from a server like

https://myabc.s3.amazonaws.com/myvideo.mp4?Expires=1730335925&AWSAccessKeyId=ACDG57GDUYHLP7LYQ46Q&Signature=%2FkR9QTXf6bdHdHA%2ByTHwXdfDfo%3D.

Now i want to show this on a website by using html video but all i got is an error. 
When i enter the url in chrome it does something and then download the video so the file exists.

How can i display this video in a video tag? or is there any possibility to do this in javascript?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What type of files are the "real" videos you have stored in S3? Not all video formats can be played natively in HTML.

Comment: most avi, swf or mp4.

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend setting the ACL to public and converting all the non-HTML5 formats to mp4 because mp4 has the most Browser support.**

You may want to try the free Cloudberry Explorer if you do not have a Desktop S3 utility.

Change your ACL Setting to Public and the file can be accessed without access keys.

Make sure the Content Type is video/mp4

Without an actual link to the mp4 I cannot pin point the problem.

If you get the same error as the sample link provided you need to generate new access keys.

If the ACL is not public and the client will generate you a set access keys there is nothing that can be done.

I was able to download the video with the link you provided.

It is an AVI file and not mp4, so it will not work in the HTML5 `<video>`.

This is the error without the Access Keys.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>63085EEB23066C91</RequestId>
<HostId>1bPb9fYkki/LnQIVRVpHfKiSEUGbfX3blBfHLQbwzjZYSzzD8hGBQFp0l9WE=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

If you are familiar with PHP, there is a simple S3 API.

[Services_Amazon_S3](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Amazon_S3/docs)

```
require_once 'Services/Amazon/S3.php';
require_once 'Services/Amazon/S3/Stream.php';
$key    = 'ASJMGERQERMGADMA';
$secret = 'hA9/wrWUMX7A0UADLNGBQEUIROH2cPjx+C';
$s3     = Services_Amazon_S3::getAccount($key, $secret);
$stream = Services_Amazon_S3_Stream::register('s3',array('access_key_id'=> $key,'secret_access_key' => $secret));
foreach ($s3->getBuckets() as $bucket){
    $name = $bucket->name ;
    $path = "s3://$name/";
}
$cnt = 0;
$ndx = 0;
$bucket = $s3->getBucket($name);
foreach ($bucket->getObjects() as $object){
    $key = $object->key;
    $url = urldecode($object->getURL());
    echo "<p>$key => $url";   
}
```

Comment: The problem is: the company i am developing for use  access keys because this is the way they upload videos for their messaging service.

Comment: What do they want you to do with the file when you access. I am watching it right now.  Does not look very confidential